# How to redirect from prestashop Home page to different URL

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I can't figure out how can I redirect  my home page to different URL. I have found tutorials how to redirect to product or category page but these doesn't work in my case.

For example:

When someone goes to myprestashop.com they will be redirected to myprestashop.com/differentpage

Sorry, if it is very simple, I'm new to prestashop and ecommerce.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried both ways from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012800/how-to-set-category-page-as-home-page-in-prestashop



With the first way I ended up with http://multiparts.lv/index.php?controller=autoparts but what I need is multiparts.lv/autoparts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to redirect page to another page

***From frontend:***

```
Tools::redirect(Context::getContext()->link->getPageLink('abc', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect only one page to a specific page, it's better (and also easier) to use .htaccess to do this.

[How to Redirect one Page url to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933812/how-to-redirect-one-page-url-to-another)